# "Glitchless" versus "Glitch-free"

Tags: terminology

Greetings English Language Subject Matter Experts,

I'm looking at a white paper from a semiconductor company. This document uses the terms "glitchless" and "glitch-free" in a way that seems interchangeable, but there are hints that "glitchless" is a special term used to describe a clock output. So, is glitchless, in fact, special? Many thanks for any light you could shed on this dim question.

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend http://electronics.stackexchange.com or http://engineering.stackexchange.com - it's definitely a matter of jargon, not general English.

Comment: If you can, look to see if the paper itself has those terms defined.  Many companies will define their own terms.   It certainly is poor writing if they are using in-consistent terms without defining them.

Comment: Yeah, these terms are meaningful to engineers, but are not well-known to the general public.

Comment: I'm going with no - [Glitchless clock switching circuit](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5623223A/en), [Glitch-free clock multiplexer](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5357146A/en)

Answer (score 0):

“Glitch-less” may be acceptable as technical jargon in the conference room. You cannot expect all engineers to be good writers. As long as the expression is understood by whom it may concern, no need to correct them. They are good at what they do.

For the rest of us, there are real words such as *flawless* and real idioms such as *without a hitch*.